# Ruby on rails - how to compute and return a value to display

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails. I have the basic down. What I want to do is when someone clicks "generate" it will take one title and one description from a large list in the db, do that 50 times, then display those on a new page.

I'm not quite sure how this is done. Is the logic for this handled in the controller or is this a rake task?

WHAT I HAVE SO FAR (I also have all the views setup):

Route:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users
  root to: "home#index"

  resources :articles
end
```

Model:

```
  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.text     "keywords"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

Controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_article, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end
  # Creates article
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end
  # Saves article
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save(article_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created #{@article.title}"
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Error creating #{@article.title}"
      render :new
    end
  end
  # renders edit page
  def edit

  end
  #updates article with new info
  def update
    if @article.update_attributes(article_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated article!"
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Error updating article!"
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # renders the article
  def show
  end

  # deletes the article
  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted!"
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Error deleting article"
    end
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title,:body,:keywords,:name)
  end

  def find_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: it has lots of aspects - you need at least a ui,  a route to accept that request and a db query to fulfill that request with meaningful content. plz share what you've done so far.

Comment: Thank you I edited the post to include what I've done so far

Answer (score 1):

Put a `generate` button on your `index.html.erb` or somewhere else.

*index.html.erb*

```
link_to "Generate", foo_articles_path, class: "some-class"
```

*routes.rb*

```
resources :articles do
  get :foo, on: :collection
end
```

then add a foo method/action to your articles controller,

```
def foo
  @articles = Article.take(50) #or some other constraints
end
```

if you want to render those in a different view (eg. foo.html.erb), create that one under `app/views/articles` path. if you name it other than `foo` (e.g `bar.html.erb`), you should explicitly include it inside `foo` action.

```
def foo
  @articles = Article.take(50)
  render :bar 
end
```

And inside that view, render `@articles` however you want.